# Windows 10でキーボードレイアウトを英語配列に設定したい

Tags: windows-10, key-mapping

キーボードの環境設定について。
TypeMatrix2030 USB Dvorakというキーボードを買いました。
このキーボードはキーボード側のボタンを押すだけでdvorakとqwertyを切り替えれるのでドライバーのインストールが不要ですが、キーボードに印刷されている記号と実際に入力される記号が違います。英語キーボードを日本語キーボードと認識しているからでしょうがどうすれば正常にキーに印刷されれている記号とおした時にディスプレイに表示される記号を一致させれますか？

因みに右上にあるshift+左向き波カッコを押すと右向きになります
"2"を押すとダブルクォーテーションになります。

現状では波カッコやカッコなどをまともに使えません。

追記:環境はWindows 10 Home 64bitです。

Comment: 環境設定のアドバイスが欲しいなら、質問本文の中にお使いの環境について記入する必要があるでしょう。 Windows 10 Home 64bit を使っているとかを質問を編集する形で追記しましょう。

Comment: この質問、プログラム関係ありますか？C言語やJavaなどでkeystate呼び出すなら分かるのですが、関連のある言語タグが無いので分かりません。HTML5だとJavaScriptとかでしょうか？OSによる環境設定の方法のみならオフトピックな気がします。

Comment: TypeMatrix2030 USB Dvorakには、別売りで文字を書いたカバーがあるらしいですよ。キーに印刷されている文字はdvorakとqwertyを切り替えたって変わりませんから、物でカバーするしかないでしょ。　この質問とソフトウェアの関連性に疑問を感じます。

Comment: 日本語環境なのに英語キーボードを使うのはプログラマくらいですから、プログラミング環境構築に関する質問ということでよいと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

該当のキーボードの現物を持っていないため推測で恐縮ですが次のURLが参考になるんじゃないでしょうか。

[Windows10日本語版で英語配列キーボードを使用する - Qiita](http://qiita.com/shimizu14/items/000cceb9e72a492b9176)

設定 → 時刻と言語 → 地域と言語 → 「日本語」をクリック後「オプション」を押下 → ハードウェアキーボードレイアウトを切り替え

もしこれでダメなら上記の「地域と言語」で「言語を追加する」→ English → 追加後に「English」をクリック後「オプション」を押下 → キーボードの追加 → 米国-Dvorak を追加

という手順を試してみると良さそうに思われます。

Comment: ご指摘の通り、
設定 → 時刻と言語 → 地域と言語 → 「日本語」をクリック後「オプション」を押下 → ハードウェアキーボードレイアウトを切り替え
で英語から日本語にしてまた英語にしたら上手く記号も打てるようになりました！ありがとうございました！